# How to copy to and from clipboard in virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualbox

I am running virtualbox 5.0.18 in ubuntu 14.04 Desktop(host machine) and I have vms running ubnutu 14.04 Server(no UI). I have enabled bidirectional clipboard sharing but still not able to copy from host and past into guest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usng the clipboard requires a GUI inside the VM. **But** it is much easier to manage a CLI only VM by connecting to it via `ssh` instead of the console window provided by Virtualbox.

And you can resize the terminal as much as you like and of course you can copy/paste there too.

If the virtual NIC is configured for NAT you will have to tell VBox (in the advanced network settings) to create port forwarding.